# Clarification on what the question wants me to do

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider

> Let the Gauss-Seidel method be applied to the equations $A \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{b}$ when $A$ is the nonsymmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix
> $$
> A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> 10 & -3 \\
> 3 & 1
> \end{array}\right] .
> $$
> Find the spectral radius of the iteration matrix. Then show that the relaxation method, described in Lecture 17, can reduce the spectral radius by a factor of 2.9. Further, show that iterating twice with Gauss-Seidel with this relaxation decreases the error $\left\|\boldsymbol{x}^{(k)}-\boldsymbol{x}^{(\infty)}\right\|$ by more than a factor of ten. Estimate the number of iterations of the original Gauss-Seidel method that would be required to achieve this decrease in the error.

I have done the first two parts with the spectral radius of the relaxed scheme being $\frac{9}{29}$.

My issue is that I do not understand what is meant by

> Further, show that iterating twice with Gauss-Seidel with this relaxation decreases the error $\left\|\boldsymbol{x}^{(k)}-\boldsymbol{x}^{(\infty)}\right\|$ by more than a factor of ten.

In the course so far the notation $x^{(k)}$ is used for the $k$-th itterate and $x^{\infty}$ to what it converges to. However, in the above I do not understand with respect to which scheme this is. Is this wrt to the original, relaexed, relaxed with two iterations? Moreover, what does iterating twice mean? Does it mean that I define a new sequence
$$
y^{k}=x^{2k}\,?
$$

I am still confused. I have tried to work with a number of these but I do not get the required end result.

**Question:**  Can someone explain what is meant by the full sentance

> Further, show that iterating twice with Gauss-Seidel with this relaxation decreases the error $\left\|\boldsymbol{x}^{(k)}-\boldsymbol{x}^{(\infty)}\right\|$ by more than a factor of ten.

Comment: Denoting $x^{(k)}$ the $k$-iterate using Gauss-Seidel, and $\tilde{x}^{(k)}$ the $k$-iterate using the relaxed Gauss-Seidel, I understand that you must show that $\left\|\tilde{x}^{(k)}-\tilde{x}^{(\infty)}\right\|$ is at least 10 times smaller than $\left\|x^{(k)}-x^{(\infty)}\right\|$.

Comment: Not entirely. The interpretation that the relaxed method converges faster is $$\left\|\tilde x^{(k+2)}-x^{(\infty)}\right\|\le\frac1{10}\,\left\|\tilde x^{(k)}-x^{(\infty)}\right\|.$$ The solution of the linear system and thus the limit of the sequences, if it exists, is the same independent of the method it was obtained with.